# Como colocar um link numa imagem usando a função "echo" php

Tags: php, link

Tenho esta função em php que pega a url atual:

```
<?php
    function UrlAtual(){
        $dominio= $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
        $url = "http://" . $dominio. $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        return $url;
    }
?>
```

Eu gostaria de usar esta url atual `<?php echo UrlAtual(); ?>` em uma imagem. Eu tentei da seguinte forma más não deu certo:

```
<a href="<?php echo UrlAtual(); ?>" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qoDmQ9q_4VI/WAoI-hJPlxI/AAAAAAAAALI/V9C0JhIDuW8SQ4JQwa6NXaLo_PE4CWwDQCLcB/s1600/02.png" width="250px"/></a>
insira o código aqui
```

Comment: O que aparece dentro do href?

Comment: Eu utilizo o Wordpress, e quando coloco o código dessa forma ai simplesmente dá erro e não carrega a página, era pra aparecer essa imagem ai https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qoDmQ9q_4VI/WAoI-hJPlxI/AAAAAAAAALI/V9C0JhIDuW8SQ4JQwa6NXaLo_PE4CWwDQCLcB/s1600/02.png com o link da função...

Comment: mas qual erro que dá? você consegue ver no log?

Comment: O erro é que a área onde fica o código não aparece, no caso o "single.php" e nem mesmo a imagem, e se eu coloco um endereço normal no lugar do <?php echo UrlAtual(); ?> ai carrega normal

Comment: Então, na verdade isso tá sendo causado pelo erro, da uma lida aqui pra ver como tu consegue detectar os erros no PHP, pra descobrir exatamente o que tá acontecendo:

https://easypiewp.com/wordpress-error-log-your-friend/

Comment: Mas esse código tá correto? Seria assim mesmo a inserção dessa função php dentro do href?

Eu pensei tbm em usar o seguinte:
<php
<a href=" echo UrlAtual();" target="_blank" rel="nofollow"><img src="https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-qoDmQ9q_4VI/WAoI-hJPlxI/AAAAAAAAALI/V9C0JhIDuW8SQ4JQwa6NXaLo_PE4CWwDQCLcB/s1600/02.png" width="250px"/></a>
?>
Estaria correto?

Comment: Do jeito que você colocou está correto, mas pode ser que ele não esteja achando essa função por exemplo, ou algum erro na função, pra saber exatamente qual é o problema, a gente deveria dar uma olhada no log de erro, sacou?

Faz o seguinte, vai na sua função comenta tudo e coloca um: return 'teste';

pra var se vai funcionar

Comment: Fiz o teste e sua função está correta. O problema provavelmente é que esta função não está no mesmo arquivo em que você está chamando ela.  Ou esta função está dentro de uma classe, então você precisa inicializar a classe para depois chamar a função.